# UICollectionView cells lining vertically instead of grid

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to create UICollectionView programatically, and my cells are getting stacked vertically instead of a grid form. 
[image]

My code is:

```
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width

    let width = (screenWidth - 4)/3
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width+20)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate=self
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView?.register(NearbyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always consider `collectionView`'s frame for item size calculation.

In your question you are using `UIScreen`'s width which might get you to wrong calculations because of `collectionView`'s `inset` properties.

> let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
>
> let screenWidth = screenSize.width

For correct size calculation lets define the number of items in single row.

`let maximumItemInRow = 3` (You can play with this as per your requirement)

Now implementing the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`'s `sizeForItem` method.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // Getting collectionView's size
    var width = collectionView.frame.width
    var height = collectionView.frame.height
    
    // Respecting collectionView's ContentInsets properties
    width -= (collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right)
    height -= (collectionView.contentInset.top + collectionView.contentInset.bottom)
    
    if let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        
        // Respecting flowLayout's sectionInset properties
        width -= (flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right)
        height -= (flowLayout.sectionInset.top + flowLayout.sectionInset.bottom)
        
        // In Vertically scrolling Flow layout
        width -= flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        height -= flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing
    }
    
    // After considering contentInset and sectionInsets 
    // we can calculate the width according to 
    // number of items in single row. 
    return CGSize(width: width / maximumItemInRow, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout as Follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let itemWidth: CGFloat = (screenWidth - 4)/3
    let itemHeight: CGFloat = itemWidth + 20

    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```